# Android - Add typed objects to spinner widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a Website class that has 3 get,set properties ID, Name, URL.

For other hand i have a method that gets from database websites, and return a List

I would like to bind this List into a Spinner.

My questions are two:

- Its possible to add these websites list into a Spinner ?
- As my website class has the property ID and Name, is possible that after a item of the spinner is selected, have the ID and Name of the item website selected ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Best Regards.

Jose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass `CursorAdapter` that will query db for the websites and set it via `yourSpinner.setAdapter(..)`.

Comment: Hi Alex, 

first of all thanks for your response.

What do you mean with subclass it? why are the benefits that i can get with it?